# Proper way to initialize state in target view controller from segue?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have an app with a simple "drill in" pattern. I present a list of items in either map mode or list mode. Clicking on one dives into a more detailed "edit" view controller. My edit controller has

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL showMap;
```

And in source implementation setter/getter methods:

```
#pragma mark - Properties
- (BOOL) showMap {
    return self.viewModeSegments.selectedSegmentIndex == 1;
}

- (void) setShowMap: (BOOL) showMap {
    self.view; // had to add this, it's a hack
    self.viewModeSegments.selectedSegmentIndex = showMap ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I set this property in the initiating controller with:

```
#pragma mark - Navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"ValveEditSegue"]) {
        ValveEditController* controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.valve = self.selections.anyObject;
        controller.showMap = ShowMap;
    }
}
```

What I discovered, is that the `showMap` setter happens before the `view` has been populated, so the `viewModeSegments` was still `nil`. I experimented with the hack shown in the setter, that forces the  access to `self.view` to make sure it's loaded. But that seems like a bad idea. What I don't know, is what pattern I *should* use instead.

I could make the `showMap` a normal property with backing, and then mirror that state into the widget at `viewDidLoad` time, but that seems silly to have a property/state just for that one time trampoline like effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the other option really...

The underlying issue is that you are using the view (or a subview) as a container of knowledge that is really shouldn't be used for. A view is for displaying knowledge, not owning that knowledge.

More broadly, it's often attractive to abuse views and the properties they offer, such as view `tag`s, cell selection state, etc, because it seems simple and wasteful to 'additionally' store that information somewhere else as well - but that doesn't make it correct to do so.

It is the responsibility of the controller to maintain the state information about what is being shown, so you should store that information in a property on the controller and maintain it there (use it to update the view, and don't query the view about its state).

Answer (score 1):

I think you understand the problem fully.  You might reduce the hacky-ness a little by forcing the view load in the from vc's `prepareForSegue`...

```
(void)controller.view;
```

But I think the answer you *should* take is your own, using a regular property.  I don't think it's silly, since the default mode of a two-mode vc is a legit property. (think of `UIViewController -hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`)